# Erro: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto, como resolver?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite, visual-studio

Possuo o método `ChamadaEfetuada(MAluno) : bool` que verifica se a chamada foi efetuada para um determinado aluno, este método e utilizado em outro método `ChamadaEfetuada() : bool` que ao invés de verificar se a chamada foi efetuada a um único aluno, ele verifica todos alunos de uma vez, e ele só retorna `true` se a chamada tiver sido efetuada para todos os alunos.

Porem estou recebendo um erro no meu método `ChamadaEfetuada() : bool` com a seguinte mensagem:

> Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

O erro ocorre nesta linha:

```
alunos[i].IdAluno = Convert.ToInt32(registro["id_aluno"]);
```

O compilador diz que o problema esta no meu array `alunos`.

Código completo do método `ChamadaEfetuada(MAluno) : bool`:

```
public bool ChamadaEfetuada(MAluno aluno) 
        {
            string query = "SELECT id_aluno FROM Lista_presenca WHERE id_aluno = " + aluno.IdAluno + " AND data = '" + this.Hoje() + "'";

            DadosConexao dados_conexao = new DadosConexao();

            SQLiteConnection conexao = this.conexao.Conexao;
            conexao.Open();

            SQLiteCommand command = conexao.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = query;            

            SQLiteDataReader registro = command.ExecuteReader();

            bool existe_registro = registro.HasRows;

            conexao.Close();

            return existe_registro;            
        }
```

Código completo do método `ChamadaEfetuada() : bool`:

```
public bool ChamadaEfetuada() 
        {
            string query = "SELECT id_aluno FROM Alunos";

            int total_alunos = 0, alunos_chamada_efetuada = 0;

            DadosConexao dados_conexao = new DadosConexao();

            SQLiteConnection conexao = this.conexao.Conexao;
            conexao.Open();

            SQLiteCommand command = conexao.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = query;

            SQLiteDataReader registro = command.ExecuteReader(); //Obtem os IDs de todos os alunos

            MAluno[] alunos = new MAluno[registro.FieldCount];

            total_alunos = registro.FieldCount;

            int i = 0;            

            while (registro.Read())
            {                
                alunos[i].IdAluno = Convert.ToInt32(registro["id_aluno"]); //Popula o atributo IdAluno do objeto alunos com os IDs obtidos pela query. Porem aqui acontece o erro.
                i++;                
            }

            conexao.Close();

            for (i = 0; i < registro.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (this.ChamadaEfetuada(alunos[i])) 
                {
                    alunos_chamada_efetuada++;
                }
            }

            if (alunos_chamada_efetuada == total_alunos)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Os dois métodos acima faz parte da minha classe `BLLListaPresenca`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se vou te ajudar porque essas mensagens de erro em português atrapalham e faltam informações que possam indicar o porquê do erro.

Eu vou chutar que você não quer o `FieldCount` afinal não interessa quantas colunas tem. Interessa quantas linhas tem, e esta informação não está disponível e aí você não pode usar um *array* (na verdade quase sempre que se usa um *array*, está cometendo um erro). Teria que usar uma lista para ir adicionando as linhas disponíveis nela. Até tem como usar o *array*, mas a gambiarra é tão grande que nem vou descrever.

Pra falar a verdade eu tenho minhas dúvidas se criar este *array* ou lista é realmente necessário. Até é neste código, mas ele está com vários problemas.

O código é muito confuso, usa técnicas erradas, códigos desnecessários, os métodos fazem mais do que deveriam, são repetitivos, inconfiáveis, inseguros, bastante ineficientes e nesta forma, um método chamar o outro deveria ser a última coisa a fazer. Precisaria de uma reestruturação completa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você esta certo o numero de colunas não e o que eu preciso, eu quero obter a quantidade de linhas que a query me retorna. Porem estou tendo dificuldades para implementar esta regra de negocio, que é verificar se a chamada do dia foi efetuada. Vc tem alguma dica de como eu posso restruturar este código?

Comment: Comece eliminando todas variáveis que são usadas zero vezes, depois as que são usadas apenas uma vez (é raro uma variável que é usada uma vez ser útil, nenhum neste caso). Dê uma lida na classe [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx). Veja como usá-la, quais o métodos e propriedades existentes eo que elas fzem. Comece usar [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), Use os [parâmetros do `SQLiteCommand `](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20017688/221800). Mude para `List<T>. Tem mais. isto é só o começo.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada aqui sobre os parâmetros do SQLiteCommand e também a classe SqlDataReader. O `List<T>` o que seria, uma lista de objeto como array? Quero me aprofundar mais a respeito.

Comment: Vai fazendo perguntas específicas com cada dúvida que tenha.

Answer (score 3):

Seguindo as recomendações do Maniero fiz as alterações no meu método `ChamadaEfetuada() : bool` e removi o método `ChamadaEfetuada(MAluno) : bool`. Substitui o array `MAlunos[] alunos` por uma lista `List<T>` e fiz a implementação da regra que é *verificar se a chamada já foi efetuada a todos os alunos* no meu método, também implementei corretamente os parâmetros do meu `SQLiteCommand` para efetuar as pesquisas.

Abaixo segue o método `ChamadaEfetuada() : bool` (reestruturado) que é a **solução** do problema acima:

```
public bool ChamadaEfetuada() 
{   
    /*Listas*/
    var alunos = new List<MAluno>();
    var alunos_chamada = new List<MAluno>();

    /*Prepara a conexão*/            
    SQLiteConnection conexao = this.conexao.Conexao;
    conexao.Open();

    using (SQLiteCommand command = conexao.CreateCommand()) 
    {                
        command.CommandText = "SELECT id_aluno FROM Alunos";

        SQLiteDataReader registro = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (registro.HasRows)
        {
            while (registro.Read())
            {
                alunos.Add(new MAluno
                {
                    IdAluno = Convert.ToInt32(registro.GetValue(0))
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            conexao.Close();
            return false;
        }

        conexao.Close();
    }

    conexao.Open();

    using (SQLiteCommand command = conexao.CreateCommand()) 
    {                
        foreach (var aluno in alunos) 
        {                    
            command.Parameters.Add("id_aluno", DbType.Int32).Value = aluno.IdAluno;
            command.Parameters.Add("data", DbType.String).Value = this.hoje;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT id_aluno FROM Lista_Presenca WHERE id_aluno = ? AND data = ?";

            SQLiteDataReader registro = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (registro.HasRows)
            {
                registro.Read();

                alunos_chamada.Add(new MAluno
                {
                    IdAluno = Convert.ToInt32(registro.GetValue(0))
                });                        
            }
            else 
            {
                conexao.Close();
                return false;
            }

            registro.Close();            
        }

        conexao.Close();
    }

    return (alunos.Count == alunos_chamada.Count);
}
```

Comment: Ainda pode ser melhorado, mas já é outra coisa. Bem melhor.

Comment: Se tiver mais sugestões pode me dizer que eu tento implementar aqui :)